# Instance method or not

Tags: python, methods

Consider the following example:

```
class Foo(object):
    def bar(self):
        return "bar"

class Bar1(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.foo = Foo()
    def bar(self):
        return self.foo.bar()

class Bar2(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.bar = Foo().bar

Bar1().bar() == Bar2().bar()
```

Which of Bar1 and Bar2 should one prefer? What are the pro/cons of the alternatives?

What I'm trying to ask is that there is an instance which has only one method, which is used in another instance. Should I make it clear that it is indeed a "method" (Bar1) or should I save one function call and some complexity (Bar2)?

Comment: Option 3: `Bar3().foo.bar()` to make it clear that there is a different object involved. If Foo’s `bar` is completely unrelated to the `Bar` type, it makes no sense to expose it as a Bar method instead.

Comment: I echo @poke's point. Where does the method naturally fit? Is it something that acts on `Bar`, or is it something that acts on some attribute of `Bar`? Put it where it feels correct. In common with the answers below, `Bar2` seems odd to me. You're pretending a method on `Foo` is a method on `Bar`, but it's always bound to a particular instance of `Foo`, so you're going to very much break expectations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Bar2` is clearly a hack (probably to reduce source length and maybe to reduce call overhead).  I would not do this.

Reasons:

① `Bar2().bar` is a method of `Foo` (which is surprising and thus no good style).  You can check this yourself by having a look at `Bar2().bar.im_self`.

② Overriding the method of `Bar2` is not possible for subclasses.  You disable a valuable feature of classes this way.

③ Changing the `Bar`'s foo later will only have the expected effect in `Bar1` while in `Bar2` the pointer to the method of the original `foo` will still be in use.

Answer (score 0):

> Should I make it clear that it is indeed a "method" (Bar1)

You should try not to expose the implementation of `Bar` to the user. Why would he care if it calls a method of some internal class? What's important is how the external API call behaves.

If you make it a method, it will imply that:

- It changes the internal state of the object, or
- It requires re-calculation on each call (just a silly example, if it represents the amount of time since the creation of the object), or
- It takes a (relatively) significant amount of time to execute and cannot be cached.

Neither seems to be applicable in your case (of course, you have more information, since you actually know what `bar()` does, and how its behavior may change in the future).